# Why is my regex is not matching a phone number that I require?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.6

My book "Automate the boring stuff with Python" has this complex regex which tries to get the phone number in a given string:

> `((\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?(\s|-|\.)?\d{3}(\s|-|\.)\d{4}(\s(ext|x|ext.)\s*\d{2,5})?)`

**222-666-7777 ext 322** is the phone number that I think should match with the regex but it doesn't. I was using regex101 and here is the link to my regex : https://regex101.com/r/OIMqNB/1. Could someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: If a book is teaching you regex with examples like this, just throw it away.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ    Nah! It was teaching the use of `VERBOSE`. It said that if we have a regex like the one above, then one should use `VERBOSE`.

Comment: will there always be an ext? or will some numbers not include it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that regex is correct, you just added a newline that broke the regex in two slices:

```
((\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?(\s|-|\.)?\d{3}(\s|-|\.)\d{4}
(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*\d{2,5})?)
```

just hit canc after {4} and put it on the same line in your regex101 link, and you'll see it works as intended.

```
((\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?(\s|-|\.)?\d{3}(\s|-|\.)\d{4}(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*\d{2,5})?)
```

It's a common error while using visual helpers, just double check your regex is on the same line everytime you see some odd behaviours

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it for you, you have just messed in placing a `?`.
Here's the new regex: https://regex101.com/r/OIMqNB/2

Comment: That's not a fix (and no fix is needed at all). you added many problems with that changes (e.g. you match also "222-666-7777 ext", which is an error.) Original regex works as intended as is better too, it just need to be in one line to work properly

Comment: I've also thought that but when I tried to put it in one line, it was not working. So I've thought there's also another problem in that. 
Btw, sorry. My fault.